# Out of memory on a 285692020-byte allocation / Bitmap Factory issue?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory, android-context

I read a few other threads on here with similar issues, but it hasn't solved my issue.

So my app, it changes the image based on a user's spinner selection. So it loads the selection from a sharedPreferences file.

The thing is, this code works on an app I made a few months ago. I am remaking my app from scratch but using code from my old app when needed. The code is identical and works on my old app but not my new one. Here is my error log:

```
DivXPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession() Not a Divx File.
PrGenericPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession() onCanHandle error
Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -8
E/MP-Decision(1802): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:7.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 46
E/MP-Decision(1802): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:147.000000
E/AudioResampler(209): Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
E/dalvikvm-heap(26650): Out of memory on a 285692020-byte allocation.
E/AndroidRuntime(26650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26650): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:835)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at com.Chris.App.Info.onCreate(Info.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(27961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Chris.App/com.Chris.App.Info}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:174)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at com.Chris.App.Info.<init>(Info.java:17)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
E/AndroidRuntime(27961):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/AndroidRuntime(26650):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/android.os.Debug(674): !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
E/EnterpriseContainerManager(674): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
E/ViewRootImpl(674): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Here is a snippit of the code, which again, works on App A but not App B?:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

final ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.selection1);
String s = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);


    if(s.equals("Nothing Selected")) {
        im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clearimage));
        im.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(s.equals("Selection 1")) {
        im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selection1image));
        im.getLayoutParams().height = 600;
        im.getLayoutParams().width = 600;
    } 
    }
```

So I seem to be getting an out of memory error and a context wrapper/issue with my share preferences??? Frustrating when the code is exact as in my other app, which works fine

Comment: You're trying to allocate 285 MB, so no surprise that you get OutOfMemoryError :)

Comment: You are trying to load a 285 MB image. This is about 10x more memory than allowed for an app.

Comment: Ick!! stupid question follow up. I didn't do anything different when I made a new Android Application in Eclipse. How do I set it lower?

Comment: Golden rule on bitmap loading: Decode only as much as you need. If your view width/height is 600 then you should only decode an 600x600 image. There are a few exceptions that you could load a slightly bigger bitmap to preserve quality but a 285MB bitmap won't do. Even with `largeHeap=true`.

Comment: Thanks dnkoutso. I actually got rid of the height/width coding and let the default image load (which is 500x404. But I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

It seems you know the views width/height. Read this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.

Also where does this bitmap come from? Wherever it comes from, its huge. You wouldn't want to download this over the web (although 285MB is the uncompressed size) and kill your users data plan.

You wouldn't even want to ship that as an asset either because people wouldn't download your app.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll make sure to read it. The thing is, all my pictures are low .png files, no more than like 500kb in size.

Comment: What are the dimensions of bitmap though? In `RGB_8888` it would be w * h * 4 bytes per pixel.

Comment: They were huge. I copied the wrong images into it >.<. Thanks for making me look. They were like 3,000x3xxx. I put the small 500 x 4xx into it. Now I just have a 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Chris.App/com.Chris.App.Info}: java.lang.NullPointerException 

error I can't fix

Comment: Seems like a different issue...must provide more details.